# Канал, книга и т.п. по типовым проектам, программам на JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, scene-builder

Подскажите хороший ютуб-канал, книгу или что-то подобное, где есть примеры проектов, программ на JavaFX, чтобы я мог изучать и разбирать способы реализаций, и учиться по факту на примерах, делая, решая свои задачи.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

По javaFX не много достойных книг, переведенных на русский язык. Мне помогло чтение этой книги в оригинале (на английском) Learn JavaFX 17 (Kishori Sharan,Peter Späth).
Книга при нулевом знании javaFX помогла мне сдать проект небольшой десктопной CRM-программы.